# Populate list in class, read list in class

Tags: c#

Am trying to make a List in class functions and populate it with id´s
   I have tested to return the count value after import and i get correct count.
   But right after the import is made and value returned the list seems to    vanish. 
   Then i try to read it outside of the class but it returns 0.

Why is the List not saved after i imported all data to it?

```
namespace Test
{
   public class program
   {
     functions functions = new functions();
     private void import()
     {
            functions.idimport(path);
     }

        private void GetIdCount()
        {
            List<string> idList = functions.GetIdList();
            var listCount = idList.Count;
            //Returns 0
        }
   }

    public class functions
    {
      private List<string> idList = new List<string>();

      public List<string> GetIdList()
        {
            return idList;
        }

        //Import ids 
        public void idimport(string path)

        { 
            string line;

            var logFile = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //Populate the list
                    idList.Add(line);

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It very well may be a valid result. Did you debug the `idimport` method? Make sure the list is populated in the first place.

Comment: Yes, as i wrote in the code i have tested to do a none void call and return the count and it is populated. And i did run it in debugg and what happends is after the import call is made the list vanish

And the List variable in the class says this 

"error CS0103: The name 'idList' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @ZaraRebeckaElisabethZentio - Your code works perfectly fine. I just ran it on a text file with 142 lines and I got the value of 142 for `listCount`.

Comment: Thats very odd when i debugg i get a locker on the list could this be an issue? Looks like this http://prntscr.com/9u1n1c but it do add values to it.

Comment: How are you consuming these classes? If you re-instantiate either one between the import function and the count function you would get 0, which seems the most likely culprit. You can see if this is the issue by making idList static and setting it to a new list at the beginning of idimport

Comment: I got "functions functions = new functions(); "
in start of my main class only there. Then i have diff calls to the methods in my class. If that is what you mean @JonathonChase

Comment: Wow, i set the list to static and dident do anything else and now i get correct count. Why is that? Seems like working when its "static"

Comment: you are loosing the scope here, when you call the `idimport` it will fill the list , but will not be filled till the next request ,to other method. It will work fine with static because it is been instantiated once.

Comment: @ZaraRebeckaElisabethZentio - Are you running this in a console app?